# Проблемы c xampp

Tags: xampp, php

Вообщем вылазит ошибка:

```
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php on line 80
```

на сколько я понимаю Config.php который мне нужен инклудится не из дириктории сайта а из папки C:\xampp\php\PEAR\ но менять имя файла не выход так как все настроено через svn и у остальных все пашет нормально как быть?

UPD: Да тянет почему-то config.php не из проекта а из PEAR отсюда и ошибки..
Указание полного пути помогает

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . 'config.php'; // pre-PHP 5.3
include __DIR__ . 'config.php'; // PHP 5.3
```

Спасибо)

Comment: Не совсем понятно, как может у всех работать правильно, а у вас нет, если сервер один и тот же. Не пробовали задавать полный путь к скриптам, как советуют на [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362870/assigning-the-return-value-of-new-by-reference-is-deprecated-in):

    include dirname(__FILE__) . 'config.php'; // pre-PHP 5.3
    include __DIR__ . 'config.php'; // PHP 5.3

Comment: @Dex, Ему пишут, что ошибка в файле config.php в строке 80.

@Руслан Либровский, приведите эту строчку, посмотрим, что там за "Assigning the return value of new by reference"

Comment: @Sh4dow, так это же PEAR это встроенная байда XAMPP. Сомневаюсь, что они ее трогали

Comment: @Dex и тем не менее, php стандартно так пишет ошибки: "[errrtype]: [description] in [file] [line]". Мож там php обновили до 5.3, или руками в файл лазили. В любом случае на строчку посмотреть надо, т.к. судя по тексту ошибки - файл подключен корректно.

Comment: @Sh4dow, согласен, но это всеобщая ошибка пользователей XAMPP. В том числе на [форуме](http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=140146), где сие творение можно скачать пишут. Но как пожелаете, вот та строка:

    $this->container =& new Config_Container('section', 'root');

Во всяком случае в моем конфиге:) Сам бодался с этой фигней несколько месяцев назад.

Comment: Так правильно) Ссылку убрать и все должно работать, если такого больше нигде нет.

    $this->container = new Config_Container('section', 'root');

Ye и таки да, привет, опенсорс) Не работает - отключите))

Comment: Вот насчет того, что нет я и сомневаюсь.